# dynamic cancan from database with complex conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, cancan, user-roles

I'm trying to define user created roles that select permissions from a list of permissions. 
I want a permission like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  user.projects_users.each do |project_user|
    project_user.role.privileges do |privilege|
      can :create, ProjectsUser, :project_id => project_user.project_id
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm trying to save privileges in a database in such a way that I can do this to get the outcome above

```
def initialize(user)
  user.projects_users.each do |project_user|
    project_user.role.privileges do |privilege|
      can privilege.action.to_sym, privilege.subject_class.constantize, privilege.conditions
    end
  end
end
```

The problem lies in the 'privilege.conditions' part. I cannot store a condition that must be executed only in the Ability.rb file. If I try to store:

```
{ :project_id => project_user.project_id }
```

It would say there is no variable named 'project_user'. I could save it as a string and in my Ability file do eval(privilege.condition), however I would need to do this only on the values. I tried something like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  user.projects_users.each do |project_user|
    project_user.role.privileges do |privilege|
      can privilege.action.to_sym, privilege.subject_class.constantize, privilege.conditions.each do |subject, id|
        subject => eval(id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is 'syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end' for the 'subject =>' piece.

Not sure how to do this exactly...

I'm using this line of commands to test it:

```
@user_id = 4
@role = Role.create(name: "Tester", project_id: 4)
@priv = Privilege.create(:action => :create, :subject_class => 'ProjectsUser', :conditions => { :project_id => 'project_user.project_id' })
@role.privileges << @priv
@project_user = ProjectsUser.create(:user_id => @user_id, :role_id => @role.id, :project_id => @role.project_id)
@a = Ability.new(User.find(@user_id))
@a.can?(:create, ProjectsUser.new(:user_id => @user_id + 1, :role_id => @role.id, :project_id => @role.project_id))
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok So I found a really easy work around. Essentially the do block on the conditions was not being evaluated correctly. Here's the working code:

```
user.projects_users.each do |project_user|
  project_user.role.privileges.each do |privilege|
    can privilege.action.to_sym, privilege.subject_class.constantize, Hash[privilege.conditions.map {|subject, condition| [subject, eval(condition)] }]
  end
end
```

Notice the `Hash[privilege.conditions.map {|subject, condition| [subject, eval(condition)] }]`

What this is doing is taking a symbol as the key in conditions such as :subject_id and mapping it to the evaluated condition, which evaluated to a particular id.

In my model I have

```
class Privilege < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  serialize :conditions, Hash
end
```

And an example model is:

```
Privilege.create(
  :action => :create, 
  :subject_class => 'ProjectsUser', 
  :conditions => { :project_id => 'project_user.project_id' }
)
```

**Update**

This method only works for conditions that are one level deep. A condition like this would NOT work. You will get a: TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String

```
:conditions => { 
  :project => { 
    :location_id => 'project_user.project.location_id'
  }
}
```

This is not the best solution, but a work around this is

```
:conditions => { 
  :project => "{ 
    :location_id => eval(\"project_user.project.location_id'\")
  }"
}
```

Comment: The problem that I am having with this implementation now is that although it works, it takes horribly long to load. Everytime you call can? on a page, it loads all possible permutations of assigned privileges...

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely say that you are going about it a bit backwards. Creating a bunch of auth rules dynamically from database records is going to be really tricky to test due to the amount of setup that is going to be required everywhere in your test suite and is rather over-complicated.

Instead use blocks to declare complex relations and roles to store privileges.

Example using the awesome [Rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) with a role scoped to a resource:

```
can :moderate, Forum do |forum|
  user.has_role?(:moderator, forum)
end
```

You can also use roles to assign privileges to groups:

```
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :crud, User
  # ...
end
```

I would say that if you really need a complex totally dynamic solution where admins create authorization rules, role definitions etc from a web interface then you have definitely outgrown CanCan. But do you REALLY need it?

Comment: Actually my boss need this feature as well. I was surprised that cancan devs has not thought about this. Described solution is not pretty good because `eval` is too vulnerable place. Guess I will just split our static roles for extra flexibility in project.

Comment: I believe that Ryan and many of the devs involved with CanCan and CanCanCan considered this and decided that its out of scope for what CanCan(Can) is supposed to achieve - a relatively simple authentication solution which is still robust. Its not really meant to the swiss army bulldozer to tackle any possible authorization problem such as where declaring the authentication rules is no longer a developer concern but rather an end user concern.

Comment: You might want to look at Pundit, since its idiom of using PORO's as policy classes offers quite a lot more flexibility - in a much cleaner fashion.

Comment: Nevertheless there is a CanCan's wiki page about DB permissions which is not enough useful.. Ok, I agree with you.

Comment: Yep, Pundit looks good. It's a bit harder to jump to another authentication module, but.. maybe) Thanks for advices.